# Going for multiple consumers - One or more queues?

Tags: java, queue, jms

I have an application that produces messages for 1000 client applications.
Each client will poll this ActiveMQ and lookup his messages.

- Should I implement one queue for every client?
- Would it be better to use one queue for all clients and diffirentiate the messages with JMS properities?

Example code with JMS properties

Producer:

```
Message message = context.createTextMessage(text);
message.setStringProperty("Client", client);
context.createProducer().send(queue, message);
```

Consumer:

```
String messageSelector = "Client = '" + client + "'";
JMSConsumer receiver = context.createConsumer(queue, messageSelector);
```

The 'client' will then be my unique client identifier. Ex: client-1; client-2; ... or a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

How many messages per second per client do you expect? All 1000 clients getting messages and that too with message selection will bring down through put. It would be a good idea to split clients across manageable number of queues.

Comment: I would have 1000 clients that poll the sever every second. The number of messages is very low. 1 every minute or slower. But when there is a message, then the client must act within a few seconds.

Comment: OK. See if you can use message listeners instead of polling the queue. A message listener will be invoked by the messaging provider when a message that matches selection criteria arrives in a queue.

Comment: Would a messageListener implementation need a 1000 connections on my server? Is this a good practice? thanks.

Comment: Since you will be running 1000 instances of client application, they all need to have a connection each to your server.